# annotating the addition of an attribute to an element

Tags: jaxb

I'm upgrading a Java object that currently has XML representation in this spirit:

```
<myObjects>
    <myObject uid="42" type="someEnum">
        <name>Waldo</name>
        <description>yada yada</description>
        <myElement>some_string</myElement>
        ...
    </myObject>
    ...
</myObjects>
```

*myElement* is optional - it can be null in Java / omitted in XML.
I'm adding a field that is **only** relevant if *myElement* has an actual value
(and to keep compatibility with previous XML, it's optional in itself)

I'm trying to avoid this:

```
    <myElement>some_string</myElement>
    <myAttr>foo</myAttr>
```

and prefer something like this:

```
    <myElement myAttr="foo">some_string</myElement>
```

but banging my head for 2 days now on how to annotate it.

- I thought of marking it with *XmlTransient* and let an *XmlAnyElement* catch it instead while unmarshalling - but it seems this will cause a problem when marshalling the object back from Java to XML.
- I tried creating an *XmlAdapter* for the element - but the unmarshal method gets only the inner content ("some_string"). **Am I missing something with this technique?**
- **Is there a way to** just get the element as a string ("<myElement myAttr=\"foo\">some_string</myElement>") and I will **process it myself?**
- **Do you recommend any other approach?**

Comment: We need to see your java

Comment: If it wasn't clear - I only need to keep compatibility with previous XML files. And I can do whatever I want with the Java code. So I intentionally didn't supply it, in order not to bias you (Blaise Doughan interpereted it pretty well below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) @XmlPath extension to easily accomplish this:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyObject {

    @XmlAttribute
    private int uid;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String type;

    private String name;

    private String description;

    private String myElement;

    @XmlPath("myElement/@myAttr")
    private String myAttr;

}
```

This class will interact with the following XML:

```
<myObject uid="42" type="someEnum">
    <name>Waldo</name>
    <description>yada yada</description>
    <myElement myAttr="foo">some_string</myElement>
</myObject>
```

Using the following demo code:

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyObject.class);

        File file = new File("input.xml");
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        MyObject myObject = (MyObject) unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(myObject, System.out);
    }

}
```

To specify MOXy as your JAXB implementation you need to include a file called jaxb.properties in the same package as your model classes with the following entry:

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

For more information on MOXy's XPath based mapping see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/09/xpath-based-mapping-geocode-example.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: Eventually I didn't use your solution (see below my own answer).
But I did learn alot from both your explantion and your blog, so I marked it as "accepted" :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer was dead simple: I'm so used to annotate with **XmlElement** and **XmlAttribute**, that I forgot about **XmlValue**!

The code for *MyObject* is the same as in Blaise Doughan answer, with one change:
*myElement* is now a class (*ElemWithAttr*) instead of String:

```
public class ElemWithAttr {
    @XmlValue
    public String content;

    @XmlAttribute
    public String myAttr;
}
```